# Radix Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I have been given some algorithms to reverse engineer. The algorithm below is a radix sort, but I am very confused about what is actually happening in the code.

I'm new to algorithms and am unsure how the code sorts elements in an array. I'm not sure what bits have to do with the algorithm and what a mask is. Here is the code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
    Integer[] zerobucket = new Integer[a.size()];
    Integer[] onebucket = new Integer[a.size()];
    int i, bit;
    Integer element, mask;

    for (bit=0; bit<8; ++bit) {
        int zc = 0;
        int oc = 0;

        for(i=0; i<array.size(); ++i) {
            element = array.get(i);
            mask = 1 << bit;
            if ((element & mask) == 0) {
                zerobucket[zc++] = array.get(i);
            } else {
                onebucket[oc++] = array.get(i);
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i<oc; ++i) array.set(i,onebucket[i]);
        for(i=0; i<zc; ++i) array.set(i+oc,zerobucket[i]);
    }
    return(array);
```

Comment: Avoid `Integer`. They are slow and waste memory. Use `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithms are where you should start learning about programming!

To see what an undocumented piece of code does, you may need to adopt a pseudo-language to put the work into an english mathematics statement.

For example, you note that this snippet should only work for 8-bit numbers (the outer loop on bit). The rough description is that the array elements are "sorted" into two buckets depending on whether the bit in position "bit" is a zero or a one -- starting with the bit in the lease significant position.  The original array is then reordered with "ones" coming before "zeros" .. which should order the array from largest to smallest.

You would be well served to look up radix sort algorithms, and start with that rather than starting with code.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm works for 8 bit numbers, and you are looking at one bit at a time. An easier to understand example is the following, using decimal instead of binary.

```
Sort on 1s:    771 721 822 955 405   5 925 825 777  28 829
Sort on 10s:   405   5 721 822 925 825  28 829 955 771 777
Sort on 100s:    5  28 405 721 771 777 822 825 829 925 955
```

After we sort on the middle digit, observe that the numbers are sorted by their
last two digits.  After we sort on the most significant digit, the numbers are
completely sorted.

The same goes for binary. 
The number of buckets we're using to sort is the **SAME as the radix of
the digit** we use as a sort key during one pass of bucket or counting sort.
"Radix" is a synonym for the **base of a number**, hence the name "radix sort." In your example, **the number is 2.**

Answer (score 0):

A [mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29), or bitmask, is used to "turn off" every bit except those that are allowed to be "seen" through the mask.  The `0`s filter out the bit they are `AND`ed with, the `1`s allow the bit through.  A common usage is to isolate a byte-sized portion of an integer data type:

```
00000000 11111111 00000000 00000000
& // Boolean AND
10010101 10010101 10010101 10010101
yields
00000000 10010101 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: While this information is true, it does not get to the heart of the problem on how to discern or describe the algorithm implemented by a set of code.

Comment: @floegipoky, true, this "answer" does not answer the _whole_ question, but it does answer the part where the OP said, "I'm not sure [...] what a mask is"

Answer (score 0):

```
/*try this iterative method and 100% working*/
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int sort();
    int display();
    long int a[20],n;
    int main(){
    int i;
    printf("enter the size:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nenter the array elements\n");
          for(i=0;i<n;i++){scanf("%d",&a[i]);}
             sort();
   return 0;
          }

int sort()
{
int p=0,rad[20],q,s=0,i=0;
int k1,k2,t; 
while(p<=3)
     {
q=0;
          while(q<=9)
               {
                 i=0;
          while(a[i]!='\0')
               {
                 t=pow(10,(p+1));
                 k1=a[i]%t;
                 k2=k1/pow(10,p);

          if(k2==q) {rad[s]=a[i];s++;}
             i++;
                }
         q++;
                }
 s=0;
 printf("\n sort for %dth\n",p);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){a[i]=rad[i];}
 printf("\n");
  display();
 p++;
       }
return 0;
       }    

int display(){
int i=0;
while(a[i]!='\0')
 {
printf("%d\t",a[i]);
i++;
 }
return 0;
              }
```

Comment: In the output sort for 0, 1,2,3,4 means units tens hundreds thousands